# How to label instructions in LLVM and identify those instructions after compilation?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

My question is how to set a label for instructions in `LLVM` optimization passes. Actually, my goal is to find a way to extract some marked `LLVM IR` instructions after compilation in `ELF` metadata of the produced executable file. What can be the most convenient way to do this? My idea was to add a label to these desired instructions in order to find them after compilation with their labels.

P.S. I am marking these instructions during an `LLVM` pass.

Thanks

Comment: You create labels using the getMDKindID() function for the module's context.  And then apply it using the instruction's setMetadata.  But I do not know how to get this metadata into the executable file, especially given that there may not be a 1:1 relation between LLVM IR and the final machine code.

Comment: @Brian I actually tried this by adding labels manually to LLVM IR which was generated by clang. Then I could see that the assembly code generated by `llc` was containing these labels as comments. And then by un-commenting those labels, we could finally find them in the executable file with `readelf`. But I am not sure this is the best way to do this.